# crm 2011 get the default view id

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there a way in CRM 2011 to get the default view id for a custom entity?  Using JavaScript I want to dynamically generate a HREF but I don't want to hard code any part of the URL.  I know how to get the Server URL and Org name in the link below but not this portion "etc=2&extraqs=%3f_gridType%3d2%26etc%3d2%26id%3d%257b"

```
http://dev:5555/MyOrg/main.aspx?etc=2&extraqs=%3f_gridType%3d2%26etc%3d2%26id%3d%257b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can query public views just like any other entity in CRM.  The entity name is [SavedQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334263.aspx) and there are properties for `returnedtypecode` (Entity Name), `isdefault`, and `querytype` ([the type of query it is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.savedqueryquerytype.aspx)).

So with that in mind you can make a query to the OData or Soap endpoints from JavaScript to get the default query for any entity type.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx

You should be able to use something like:

```
var defaultViewId = Xrm.Page.getControl("<lookup field name>").getDefaultView()
```